# Java, HttpURLConnection and setting the content length

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, content-length

I'm setting the length of the content in my HttpURLConnection, for a PUT.

```
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + responseJSONArray.toString(2).getBytes("UTF8").length);
```

The actual number of bytes is 74. However, when I query the content length of `urlConnection` I'm returned `-1`. Why is that? And why are lengths not equal (given that I set this)?

I must set the content-length because I'm receiving a `411` response from the server.

(Also, in the Sun [examples](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/ttips/HTTPPost/) I've seen the second argument of `setRequestProperty` is of type `int` and not `String`, which seems odd.)

Comment: I answered this question and I realise now that it's got an android tag. I have no idea how Google implemented `HttpURLConnection`.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman they would have had to agree with the existing Javadoc specification, and your misunderstandings didn't have anything to do with possible variations among implementations.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You shouldn't set this header yourself. Use `setFixedLengthStreamingMode()` or `setChunkedTransferMode()`.

Comment: Thanks. I still don't understand something: I'm now doing `urlConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(responseJSONArray.toString(2).getBytes("UTF8").length);`. The body-length is `74` bytes, however when I call `Log.v("app", "" + urlConnection.getContentLength());` I see `-1`. Why is that?

Comment: @SK9 that's the length of the *response.*

Comment: Thanks. That seems needlessly ambiguous to me!

Comment: @SK9 nothing ambiguous about it. There is no reference in the Javadoc to the content length of the request. It is all about the response.

Comment: @SK9 of course, but you asked about `getContentLength(),` which is what I answered about.

Comment: I have set setFixedLengthStreamingMode(), but i  getContentLength() still return -1 at server client. Is there someone solve this problem?

Comment: @boiledwater Did you set it before you started to write the output?

Comment: @boiledwater Why? It says exactly what I have told you here.

Answer (score 3):

Also do not forget to add a [setDoOutput](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setDoOutput%28boolean%29) to tell your connection you are going to send data.

Comment: Thanks. I already am (with `urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);`).

Comment: It should rightfully be -1, since you are sending data not getting some from the server. 
getContentLenght(): "Returns the content length in bytes specified by the response header field content-length or -1 if this field is not set."
From [Android Javadoc for HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)

Comment: Hmm - I thought the content-length field specified the byte-length of the HTTP request I was preparing.

Comment: What should be -1? The question is about the request content-length. Your quotation is about the response content-length. Your remark doesn't make sense.

Answer (score -2):

I get same error with "Content-Length" -

```
        URL url = new URL(targetURL);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authKey);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(requestJSON.getBytes().length));
```

And I finally deduced that it happens because one of the Json object fields contains diacritical characters.

```
        someCategory = "Ţepuşă";
        try {
        JSONObject postData = new JSONObject();
        postData.put("category", someCategory);
        .....
```

That's what the error looks like:

```
08-27 18:57:07.842 24263-24263/ro.nexuserp.documentecontabile E/Eror: content-length promised 491001 bytes, but received 491000
```

Comment: The error is that you shouldn't set it at all. Java will set it for you. This was stated, several times, eight years before you posted.